# Creating an Array of Threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a very strange problem with my code. It will fully run the 1st for loop, then complete the foreach, but then it will skip back to the "ThreadStart IMAPDelegate" (line 1 of the for loop) and then crash because of an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Can someone explain why the program is doing this? I debugged it line by line and it literally just skips back up into the a line in the for loop. If it had normally run the for loop again, it would have set x back to 0 and it would not have crashed. Any suggestions?

```
for (int x = 0; x < UserInfo.Count; x++)
{
    ThreadStart IMAPDelegate = delegate{SendParams(UserInfo[x], IMAPServers[x]); };
    MyThreads.Add(new Thread(IMAPDelegate));
}

foreach (Thread thread in MyThreads)
{
    thread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design when you use an anonymous method like that.  As soon as the thread starts running, it executes the SendParams() method call.  Which then bombs because the "x" variable is already incremented beyond UserInfo.Count.  Fix:

```
for (int x = 0; x < UserInfo.Count; x++)
{
    int user = x;
    ThreadStart IMAPDelegate = delegate{SendParams(UserInfo[user], IMAPServers[user]); };
    MyThreads.Add(new Thread(IMAPDelegate));
}
```

Comment: +1 Otherwise know as "Closing Over the Loop Variable":(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx.

Comment: When when UserInfo and MyTheads both have more than 1 element, it gives me the error.

Count = Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.

Comment: That's not an error, just the debugger complaining that it temporarily lost its marbles.  That happens.  There's a hotfix for debugger problems with threads when you use VS2008.  Or press F5.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912

Comment: Now only the 1st thread in the array will start, all others will not.

Comment: Hmya, threads don't just refuse to start when you call their Start() method.  I'm going to guess that anonymous methods really confuse the stuffing out of you.  There's no compelling reason to use them here, this will work just as well when you use a little private helper method as the ThreadStart delegate target.

Comment: This is getting very strange. It appears that 1 thread will randomly not start. I think it may have something to do with the values of user being different when each thread starts. Is there any way to prevent the thread from going back into the for loop after I create it?

Comment: "thread going back into the for loop" is what is *supposed* to happen when you use an anonymous method.  Again, if this confuses you then don't use them.

Comment: Is there any other way to create an array of threads with multiple parameters and then start them all?

Comment: Great topic for another question.

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix it. I added some extraneous Threads to the array. Those failed to start, but the ones I wanted to start, actually did. A strange way to solve the problem, but it works.